# Specifying absolute directory paths within jupyter

Tags: string, jupyter-notebook

I am still making my way through transitioning into iPython using Jupyter notebooks. All I am trying to do is specify a path name as a string. For subsequent operations, I am importing other packages which seem to have been done correctly. But I can't define the pathname as a string. The code is provided below:

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import os

file_path = 'C:\Users\shikh\PlayWithPython\Kaggle\titanic\Data'
```

---

The error message:

[image: error message]

What is the right way to do this? I want to keep my subsequent calls to pd.read_csv and other commands simple and iterable. Any suggestions?
Many thanks in advance.
Souvik

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys ... solved the issue. And I don't need to import os either. Here's the import protocol for anybody else with MATLAB habits switching to Python :)

```
import pandas as pd 
file_path = 'C:\\Users\\shikh\\PlayWithPython\\Kaggle\\titanic\\Data\\' 
file_name = 'train.csv' 
df_train = pd.read_csv(file_path+file_name)
```